# Rotate an object to stay in front of camera

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, euler-angles

I'm doing a VR menu and I'm trying to get the menu to stay in front of the camera. I'm trying to get the menu to slide up when you look down and be fixed to the bottom of view. The menu is based on a number of menu items arranged in a curve.

Here is the code http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/BLOwLj (I've had to use Orbit Controls rather than VR controls in this CodePen, I can't get VRControls to work in CodePen but they are working fine in my actual code)

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1024);
camera.position.x = 1;
scene = new THREE.Scene();

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
// controls = new THREE.VRControls(camera);
// controls.standing = true;

dolly = new THREE.Group();
dolly.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( dolly );
dolly.add( camera );

menu = new THREE.Object3D();
....
child.add(menu);
```

And then in the render function trying things like

```
menu.rotation.x = - 1 - camera.rotation.x;
```

Currently it will slide up and down when the camera tilts, but it also slides up and down when the camera rotates.

What's the easiest way to get the object to rotate on the X axis when the camera tilts via VR Controls?